# How to increment the loop if it does not match the id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I'm working on a code which displays the images from the AWS server. But I'm facing trouble in looping the code.

It works fine for the 1st display but it is not going further (I've to display upto 6 images)

code for this -

```
def get_image_urls(user)
        user_identifications = user.user_identifications.where(current_flag: true).order(:id_dl)
        urls = []
        keys = []
        if !user_identifications.empty? && !user_identifications.nil?
            user_identifications.each_with_index do |each_id, index|
                obj = S3_BUCKET.object(each_id.aws_key)
                urls << {each_id.id_dl=> obj.presigned_url(:get)}
                keys << {each_id.id_dl=> each_id.aws_key}
            end
        end
        return urls, keys
    end
```

How to increment the loop based on checking the id and user.identifications value?

Comment: `!user_identifications.empty? && !user_identifications.nil?` to `user_identifications.present?`

Comment: code seems ok. user_identifications has more than one value??

Comment: Yes. It has 6 values in total. I want to display all of them in order irrespective of the upload.
So I'm using a flag. Based on its status, I want to display the images @AbibullahRahamathulah

Answer (score 0):

`reject` all empty values and then iterate `users_identifications`.
Like:

```
sanitized_identifications = users_identifications.reject(&:blank?)
sanitized_identifications.each_with_index do |identification, _index|
  # Now if you want to skip an iteration based on some condition, try `next`, like:
  # next if some_condition
  # in you case
  obj = S3_BUCKET.object(each_id.aws_key)
  next if obj.blank?
  urls << {each_id.id_dl=> obj.presigned_url(:get)}
  keys << {each_id.id_dl=> each_id.aws_key}
end
```

**UPDATE**

```
# ...
user_identifications.each_with_index do |each_id, index|
  begin
    obj = S3_BUCKET.object(each_id.aws_key)
    urls << {each_id.id_dl=> obj.presigned_url(:get)}
    keys << {each_id.id_dl=> each_id.aws_key}
  rescue => e
    next
  end
end
#...
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is as same as the one which I'm working on with few changes in the variable. I'm looking for something which will skip the empty field and go to the next field!

Comment: `empty field` means `obj.empty?`

Comment: Yes it is. Some fields may not have any contents and some will have. That's where the increment should happen which will skip the empty fields

Comment: I've mentioned it earlier, anyways I've updated my answer. Try it :)